# Does Google return to visit a page with 404 Error?

Tags: web-crawlers, googlebot, 404

If a page indexed in Google shows a 404 Error, does Google return to visit it again?

In other words, if a page that was indexed in Google continue to show the 404 Error for several years, will Google use its bandwith to crawl it again during these years?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nice question. The short answer is yes. As long as the error 404 URL has internal/external links pointing to them, Google will eventually visit the page. We can check this through:

- Google Search Console: we can see errors from several months ago.
- Analyzing server logs: we can see searchers visiting error 404 and 410 pages after those URLs were deindexed.

Maybe they could have an end date for checking an error but if that were true, once a URL is marked as gone it would never show up again in searchers (except if it gets new links). In my opinion, that way is far more complex than checking all URLs and classified the good ones and those which generates an error.

The reality is more complex than a yes/no answer. In [this experiment](https://www.mjcachon.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/tiempos-desindexacion.png), they tried several methods for deindexing URLs and in the last column, you can see a yes/no option whether the URL was visited after the deindexation or not.

Comment: "In this experiment ..." - Looks useful. However, do you have an English translation or link to the full article?

Comment: Sure, it's in Spanish but you can easily translate it with Google: https://www.mjcachon.com/blog/test-desindexar-urls/