# Redirected page need to make no-index on google

Tags: seo, googlebot, search-engine-indexing, links

All images used in WordPress website have got a URL and WordPress automatically created a URL for a landing page using the image.php file. So protecting to index all images with dedicated pages URL I removed all code and redirect all images link to the homepage. Which is working fine whenever someone clicks on the image link it automatically redirects to the homepage.

But the image's URL are not getting deindexed from search results. So that is damaging website and getting bad redirect messages on websmater.

Can anyone help me how I can deindex all images from SERP? Want to deindex all URLs so that I won't need to redirect these URLs to the homepage.

Comment: How long has it been?   Redirecting to the home page is a "soft 404" to Google and Google will treat the URLs the same as if you removed them at let them give a 404 error.   However, it could take Google several weeks to find that all the pages have been removed and remove them from the search results.   Have you waited that long?

Comment: Alternately you could redirect the page for the image to the image itself.    I know that Yoast has a feature that will do that: https://kb.yoast.com/kb/redirect-image-attachment-urls/    That would be better for users than taking the user to the home page because users would still get the content they are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The best SEO option would be that each URL image redirects to the actual URL in which is shown instead of the homepage. That would help users and searchers to find what they were looking for.

#### Remove the URLs

You could use the [Google URL removal tool](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/url-removal) but it's only for individual URLs so in case that you have tons of URLs to remove it's not a plausible solution.

You can try, instead of redirect, to throw a `410 error`. Although [Google still visits error pages](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/117582/does-google-return-to-visit-a-page-with-404-error/117583#117583), those are deindexed faster than a redirected URL.

Comment: The Google URL removal tool only removes URLs temporarily, afaik. The rest of the answer is good advice though.